# TetGenLink Assertion failure

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry, interoperability, mesh, tetgenlink

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];

TetraMaker[pts_, surface_, TetGenString_?StringQ] := 
Module[{inInst, outInst, coords, surface1, meshElements, facets}, 
        inInst = TetGenCreate[];
        TetGenSetPoints[inInst, pts];
        facets = Partition[surface, 1];
        TetGenSetFacets[inInst, facets];
        outInst = TetGenTetrahedralize[inInst, TetGenString];
        coords = TetGenGetPoints[outInst]; (* element point *)
        surface1 = TetGenGetFaces[outInst]; (* element face *)
        meshElements = TetGenGetElements[outInst]; (* element indices *)
      {coords, surface1, meshElements}];

 TetrahedraVolume = 
         Compile[{{coords, _Real, 2}, {elements, _Integer, 1}}, 
         Block[{p}, p = coords[[elements]];
             1/6*Abs[Det[p[[{1, 2, 3}]] - p[[{2, 3, 4}]]]]], 
              RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];




 {coords1, surface1, meshElements1} = TetraMaker[data01, polysurface1, "pqa.8"];
  vb = Total[TetrahedraVolume[coords1, meshElements1]]
  Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords1, Polygon[surface1]]]
```

Error dialog appears when running code below:

```
 {coords2, surface2, meshElements2} = TetraMaker[data02, polysurface2, "pqa.8"];
  vb = Total[TetrahedraVolume[coords2, meshElements2]]
```

> Assertion failed!
>
> Program: ...
>   File: M:\Builds\2615350\checkout\Mathematica...\tetgen.cxx
>   Line: 21962
>
> Expression: dir !=COLLOSIONFACE
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)

I am trying to calculate volume. I wonder if both data sets are similar then why does it not work for 2nd data set? Is there any way I can fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second data set has intersecting facets. There is no way TetGen can tetrahedralize that.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
res = TetGenDetectIntersectingFacets[data02, 
   Partition[polysurface2, 1]];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[res[[1]], Polygon[res[[2]]]]]
```

[image]

So the solution is to fix the data set. I have to see about how to improve the assertion error. The problem is that there are duplicate faces. If you use

```
sf2 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ polysurface2];
{coords1, surface1, meshElements1} = 
  TetraMaker[data02, sf2, "pqa.8"];
vb = Total[TetrahedraVolume[coords1, meshElements1]]
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords1, Polygon[surface1]]]
```

it will work.

Comment: @Jay, this update should do it. I am curious, could you comment on what type of data this is and what the application is?

Comment: @Jay, interesting. Is this lab data? How do you get the surface facets of the particles?

Comment: @Jay, thanks for the clarification. Concerning the contour selection, one would need to see an example to say how this could be done in Mathematica.

Comment: @Jay, I think it were good if you were to post this part as a new question. Many more people will then look at this.